# cudaModuleLoadData fails with error code 201

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu

I have a ptx code that I want to execute on the GPU. I am using the following code to this:

```
CUmodule cudaModule;

//the variable that stores the error associated with cuda API calls.
CUresult cudaErrorVariable;

//variable representing any cuda kernel function.
CUfunction CUDAPipelineKernel;

//initializing cuda driver
cudaErrorVariable = cuInit(0);

//checking for error while loading ptx code in CUmodule.
if(cudaErrorVariable != CUDA_SUCCESS){
    myLogger->error("Unable to initialize CUDA driver");
    return 1;
}

//loading the ptx code into the module.
cudaErrorVariable = cuModuleLoadData(&cudaModule, PTXCode);

//checking for error while loading ptx code in CUmodule.
if(cudaErrorVariable != CUDA_SUCCESS){
    cuGetErrorString(cudaErrorVariable, (const char **)&errorString);
    myLogger->error("Unable load ptx file into the module : CUDA Error {}", cudaErrorVariable);
    return 1;
}
```

The cuModuleLoadData function return an error code 201. I have no idea what this error code means. Could someone help me identify the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the relevant [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__TYPES.html#group__CUDA__TYPES_1gc6c391505e117393cc2558fff6bfc2e9), Error 201 is `CUDA_ERROR_INVALID_CONTEXT` which means you have not correctly set up a context prior to trying to load a module.

Comment: How do you setup a context?

Comment: @RegisPortalez: It is a community wiki answer -- edit whatever additional information you want into the answer. That is why it was created that way. The code in the original question is broken in lots of ways which need fixing beyond just the lack of context creation

Comment: Didn't know the point of community wiki answers. And I don't have the answer to question. 
I just thought that a RTFM answer was not really helpful as the manual basically says that the "context is invalid"...

Comment: @RegisPortalez But it was, in its essence, an RTFM question ("I have an error number, can some what tell me what it means") and the answer does exactly that, along with the teaching point of where to find the documentation for the codes, given that the driver API doesn't have and error code to text helper functions

Answer (score 2):

Here is the link to [cuInit](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__INITIALIZE.html#group__CUDA__INITIALIZE), which is the first and foremost function to be called before any cuda driver API call, as stated in documentation.

For completeness, here is the link to context creation: [cuCtxCreate](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__CTX.html#group__CUDA__CTX_1g65dc0012348bc84810e2103a40d8e2cf).

You may also use the [Primary context](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__PRIMARY__CTX.html), as inspired by the `6_Advanced/ptxjit` sample in the cuda samples directory, which is lazy initialized with `cudaMalloc`.

> The primary context is unique per device and shared with the CUDA
>   runtime API. These functions allow integration with other libraries
>   using CUDA.

Comment: The question is "I have no idea what this error code means. Could someone help me identify the error?". How does this answer the *question*?

Comment: @talonmies, I understood the question differently. You answerd to "Could someone help me find the meaning of the error code?", I tried to answer, "Could you help me solve my issue in my code that lead to the error ?".

Comment: I answered the literal question which was asked. That is kind of how question and answer works, as far as I am aware

Comment: @talonmies, I maybe wrongly assumed the OP had an idea of the error code meaning due to the call to `cuGetErrorString`. The question can be understood both ways IMHO. I don't believe the verb identify is used for look-up in an error table here.